# Background color automatic cycle with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, colors, rotation

I have 3 divs set up on my website, and at the moment I am using CSS3 to highlight each div for 5 seconds by changing the background colour. So the first div highlights for 5 seconds, then the 2nd then the 3rd. Can I acheive the same thing with Javascript?

My html is

```
<a href=""><div class="highlight" id="caption2">
Text1
</div></a>
<a href=""><div class="highlight" id="caption3">
Text2</div></a>
<a href="">
<div class="highlight" id="caption4">
Text3</div></a>
```

Js

```
      $("div.highlight").each(function (i) {
    var $self = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $self.removeClass("highlight")
        $self.addClass("caption");
        setTimeout(function () {
         $self.addClass("highlight");
            $self.removeClass("caption");
        }, 1000);
    }, i * 1000);
});
```

CSS

```
#caption2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:-20px;
    z-index:50;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
    overflow:hidden;

}
#caption3 {
    position:absolute;
    top:70px;
    left:-20px;
    z-index:70;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
        overflow:hidden;


}
#caption4 {
    position:absolute;
    top:130px;
    left:-20px;
    z-index:50;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
        overflow:hidden;


}

.highlight {
    background-color:#000;
}
.caption {
    background-color:#f1583c;   
    color:yellow;   
}
```

Comment: can you put your code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure! Nothing simpler than this:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div")

for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(n){
        divs[n].className = "highlight";
    }, i * 1000, i);
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/e4Qv4/

Or if you want it more jQuery'ished, take something like this:

```
$("div").each(function(i){
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        self.className = "highlight";
    }, i * 1000);
});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/e4Qv4/1/

**Update**

Your main problem is the css-selector specificity... An ID gets an higher rate then a class. The other thing is, that you've misunderstood my solution. Read a bit about the Sizzle-Selector engine, which is built in jQuery, that should help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's great except, I want the divs to be highlighted individually, so the first div highlights, then it returns to normal as the 2nd div is highlighted, then the same for the 3rd. So the active state cycles through the divs. Thankss @yckart

Comment: @KieranVyas http://fiddle.jshell.net/e4Qv4/2/ To get good answers, ask good questions ;)

Comment: Ok sorry! Even my updated question is poor! SORRY. I need the cycle to loop? So it goes back to the first div once it has completed. THANK YOU FOR YOUR TIME! :D @yckart

Comment: @KieranVyas are you sure that you cannot fiddle that yourself?

Comment: well i tried, i'm just having problems. I cannot get the script to work for my specific divs instead of all divs. @yckart

Comment: I have shared it in my question. Thanks @yckart

Comment: @KieranVyas I hope your customers don't have to pay for your time! That what you're doing is the complete wrong way... Learn how to build awesome websites and therefore don't sell them before!

Comment: What do you mean it's the complete wrong way? I just copied your code. @yckart

Comment: Yeah, and **this** is the wrong way... Don't use without thinking!

Comment: ok well I have fixed it now, and updated my code in the question. Just don't know how to make it continually loop? Thank you @yckart